# Pass the ggplot2 title inside a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, eval, caption

I need to specify a title that is determined by the column selected for a ggplot graph. I need to be able to make graphs for several of the columns in the data frame.

```
cola <- c(11, 13, 17, 12, 34)
colb <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
colc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dfb <- data.frame(cola, colb, colc)

library(ggplot2)
graph_func <- function(col) {
  dfb %>% ggplot(aes(x=colc, y=!!col)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(title = !!col)
} 

graph_func(quo(colb))
```

I wanted the title to read 'colb' but I get an error message:

> ```
> > Error in ggtitle(caption = !!col) : unused argument (caption = !!col)
> ```

Comment: `ggittle()` does not take argument "title". As you pass a quoted arg, in your example ,`ggtitle(col)` should work

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to quote the argument. Use !!enquo brackets {{ }} instead:

```r
graph_func <- function(col) {
  dfb %>% ggplot(aes(x=colc, y= {{ col }})) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(enquo(col))
} 

graph_func(colb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `` deparse(substitute(`var`) ``:

```
graph_func <- function(col) {
  dfb %>% ggplot(aes(x = colc, y = !!col)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(deparse(substitute(col)))
}

graph_func(colb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(ggplot2)
 graph_func <- function(col) {
  col <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(col))
   dfb %>% ggplot(aes(x=colc, y=.data[[col]])) +
     geom_point() +
     ggtitle(col)
 }
graph_func(colb)
```